# vim partial repeat command

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

Sometimes I want to repeat a whole command and I use the dot command, but sometimes I want to repeat only a part of that command. Is there a command or a plugin that allows to do that ?

Let's say the initial command was `caW foo`. Is there a way to repeat only the `caW` part ?

Comment: I'd say if you're doing a lot of `caW` just map that to another temporary key. Other than that, a 3 strokes command already looks very minimal so I'm not sure if a whole plugin is needed, to add yet more maps...And no, natively you can't just repeat that part.

Comment: May be you can record and play when needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think we can't do it natively. Besides, how can we remember all of our old typed command? For me, I personally can't remember it because I only focusing on the text/code.

IMHO, the main purpose of the repeat command (.) is just to repeat our last command easily. So, instead of type it again and again, we just do it using dot (.) command :)